# Amazon Cognito - Convert Guest user identity as Authenticated user

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, xamarin.ios, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon cognito service in my Xamarin iOS application where I have feature for user to login as guest and using facebook account. Facebook login feature is working great, But I want to add option for guest user to convert their guest account to facebook authenticated account.

I have added user history to dynamodb table according to user identity Id for both guest and facebook authenticated user. So when guest account will be converted to facebook authenticated account, I need the identity Id to be same. Is it possible?

Currently I have just sync guest information without calling

```
credential.AddLogin(PROVIDER,TOKEN);
```

This creates an unauthenticated identity and stores the info.

I thought without clearing this identity from cache, if I try to login using facebook, this identity will be merged as authenticated identity. But that is not happening.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html)? Specifically, have you tried doing something like this?

```
CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials (
    "IDENTITY_POOL_ID",    // Cognito Identity Pool ID
     RegionEndpoint.USEast1 // Region
);
...
credentials.AddLogin("graph.facebook.com", accessToken.Token);
...
var identityId = await credentials.GetIdentityIdAsync();
```

Comment: yes, I have implemented login using facebook in my app. My question is if user first logs in as a guest, then if he wants to merge this identity as facebook authenticated identity, is it possible? And after this will the identityId be same?

Comment: Yes, adding a login to an unauthenticated identity will make it become an authenticated one. If there is already an authenticated id linked to that login, a merge of the existing one and the new one will kick off, and the identity id used at the end could be either. If no existing id is linked to that token already, then the unauthenticated id will be used.